# Perl memory usage with map and file handle

Tags: perl, file, dictionary, memory-management, filehandle

Does calling `map { function($_) } <FILEHANDLE>;` load the entire file into memory when using perl?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes -- or at least that's how I interpret this outcome.

```
$ perl -e "map {0} <>" big_data_file
Out of memory!

$ perl -e "map {0} 1 .. 1000000000"
Out of memory!
```

One might wonder whether we run out of memory because Perl is trying to store the output of `map`. However, my understanding is that Perl is optimized to avoid that work whenever `map` is called in a void context. For a specific example, see the discussion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083269).

Perhaps a **better example**:

```
$ perl -e "sub nothing {}  map nothing(), <>" big_data_file
Out of memory!
```

Based on the comments, it appears that the question is motivated by a desire for a compact syntax when processing large data.

```
open(my $handle, '<', 'big_data_file') or die $!;

# An ordinary while loop to process a data file.
while (my $line = <$handle>){
    foo($line);
}

# Here Perl assigns each line to $_.
while (<$handle>){
    foo($_);
}

# And here we do the same thing on one line.
foo($_) while <$handle>;
```

Comment: A simple enough test case. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, in both cases you are loading a list with `0` values. You will get the same error if you use a for loop and `push` zeroes onto an array. Although in that case, it is not instantaneous.

Comment: I'm not loading the returned data into an array though; `map { print FILEHANDLE function($_) } <FILEHANDLE>;`. I just prefer to use map on small operations instead of foreach.

Comment: @Eric Pruitt An alternative would be the following: `print FILEHANDLE function($_) while <FILEHANDLE>;`.

Comment: @FMc There's an idea. I don't quite understand how that syntax works though (new to perl). Could you explain it?

Comment: @TLP As I understand it, when called in a void context, `map` does not assemble a return list, so there is no giant list of zeros in my first two examples. Nonetheless, your comment is on target in suggesting that I should have used a better example (see edited answer).

Comment: @Eric if you are reading and writing to the same filehandle, i.e. editing a file in place, you might consider using File::Tie or perl's edit in place feature.

Comment: @TLP I'm not editing in place. I just didn't distinguish the two handles (and I can't edit anymore). It should be `print FILEHANDLE1 function($_) while <FILEHANDLE2>;`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the operands for `map`, foreach loop and sub calls are evaluated before `map`, the foreach loop or the sub call even begins.

One exception:

```
for my $i (EXPR_X..EXPR_Y)
```

(with or without `my $i`) is optimised into a counting loop, something along the lines of

```
my $x = EXPR_X;
my $y = EXPR_Y;
for (my $i = $x; $i <= $y; ++$i)
```

Perl6 will have native support for lazy lists.

Comment: What do you mean by "sub calls?"

Comment: @Eric Pruitt, `f()`, the arguments being the operands.

Answer (score 2):

The question you are asking I assume is this: Does the `map` function slurp the file before it begins processing, or does it use line by line.

Lets do a quick comparison about handling lists:

```
while (<FILEHANDLE>) { ... }
```

This case clearly uses line by line. Each iteration, a new value for `$_` is fetched.

```
for my $line (<FILEHANDLE>) { ... }
```

In this case, the `LIST` is expanded before the loop starts. In http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html there is a reference to `map` being similar to a `foreach` loop, and I do believe that `LISTs` are expanded before being passed to a function.

Comment: I don't think it's moot in this case: `map { print FILEHANDLE function($_) } <FILEHANDLE>;` EDIT: It appears that it does load the file into memory (see FMc's answer), so I will use a foreach loop instead of a map.

Comment: @Eric Yeah, you're right.. there's no clear answer about the mootness, because map can do whatever it wants. I'll remove that part..